# How to run pre-commit hooks using husky v7 only on frontend project if frontend and backend has same repository

Tags: next.js, pre-commit-hook, pre-commit, husky

This is my project structure

```
 - .git
 - frontend/
     -.husky/
 - backend/
```

I have implemented husky with lint-staged in frontend folder only but pre-commit is running even where there is a change in backend folder only.

**package.json**

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext tsx",
    "prepare": "cd ../ && husky install ./frontend/.husky"
  },
"devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "17.0.10",
    "@types/react": "17.0.38",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.10.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.10.1",
    "eslint": "7.11.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "12.0.8",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.28.0",
    "husky": "^7.0.4",
    "lint-staged": "^12.3.2",
    "typescript": "4.5.4"
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "*.tsx": "eslint --ext .tsx"
  }
```

**.husky/precommit**

```
#!/bin/sh
. "$(dirname "$0")/_/husky.sh"

cd ./frontend
npx lint-staged
```

I want to run husky pre-commit only if anything changes in the frontend folder and want backend to remain unaffected.

Comment: Git doesn't have per-directory hooks, they're installed in the _repo_.

Comment: Yes I got your point. But is there any way to achieve this? Can husky ignore any particular directory?

Comment: This article might answer your question https://devsday.ru/blog/details/50660